# Clarification of Game Theory Exercise

Tags: game-theory

Look at the second exercise here: (open yale course on game theory)

http://oyc.yale.edu/sites/default/files/problemset1_1.pdf

Does anyone understand the meaning of this from question a)

"What common amount of effort s^** should they agree each to supply to the firm if their aim is to maximize revenue net of total effort costs. "

What doe "revenue net of total effort costs" mean ?

Sorry, English is not my first language!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be called "operating profits"....just take the total sales and subtract the costs to provide the services.